# Qt & OpenGL - rendering off-screen : QGLFrameBufferObject?

Tags: qt, opengl, rendering, off-screen

i'm new to OpenGL and i need to use a `QGLFrameBufferObject` for off-screen rendering (or solve my problem with grabFrameBuffer, see below). I read the example in Qt Documentation, but there are too many things at once, it is kind of difficult for me.
Could someone explain me the different steps to use a QGLFrameBufferObject.
I'd like to create a buffer and add several images inside (with `setTransform()` also) and then save just a part of it into a PNG image with transparency.

How to proceed ?

I've read several topic about people having trouble with different points for this kind of thing, so I guess it is gonna be tough ...

In fact i've already done all this into a `QGraphicsView` with a `QGLWidget` as Viewport, but using `grabFrameBuffer` to save the scene doesn't work (transparency problem and I can't use grabFrameBuffer if I want to `.hide()` the scene ... do I ?).

Comment: Me again. I'm getting somewhere with `QGLFrameBufferObject`.
I succeeded to render images of size 7574*2303 for example, but when i go to over around 8000*2700, i got **"Framebuffer incomplete attachment"**.
So, is there a **size limit for QGLFramebufferObject** and if so, what is it ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I decided to cut into several images when it's too big.
Is there any faster way to the **QGLFramebufferObject content**, than `.toImage().save("name","png");` ?

Comment: there is a limit in the graphics card's memory. On my NVidia card the max texture dim is 8192 for example